# Cleanest way to do multiple response.redirects without page refresh?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, asp.net

I am trying to develop a simple web part in VS that will pull data from a text box, construct a URL with the data and open a new tab using `OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"` and using this on the code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String myString = TextBox1.Text;

        Response.Redirect("http://..." + myString + "...");
}
```

This works, but it will only work once from my site without a page refresh.  What is the best way to either allow multiple redirects without refresh or just simultaneously refresh the page so the user can enter and search a different parameter?

Comment: This question is borderline to be off topic (remove the webpart part and it is an asp.net question), and I also think it would get more attention on the stackoverflow site

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx", true);
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have mentioned that the destination URL is an external site. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151439/which-one-is-better-server-transfer-and-response-redirect) Server.transfer only works on same server/domains.  I tested anyways and they are correct.